# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {en, nl}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router

I am setting up a React app. I am getting the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {en, nl}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

**19 stack frames:**

`throwOnInvalidObjectType`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13231

`reconcileChildFibers`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14133

`reconcileChildren`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16990

`updateHostComponent`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17632

`beginWork`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19080

`HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945

`invokeGuardedCallbackDev`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994

`invokeGuardedCallback`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056

`beginWork$1`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964

`performUnitOfWork`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22776

`workLoopSync`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707

`renderRootSync`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670

`performSyncWorkOnRoot`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293

`scheduleUpdateOnFiber`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21881

`updateContainer`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25482

`(anonymous function)`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26021

`unbatchedUpdates`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22431

`legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26020

`render`
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26103

Here you can find the `index.tsx` file.

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import MainApp from './router'

const page = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <MainApp />
  </BrowserRouter>
)

const app = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(page, app)
```

Here you can find the `router.tsx` file

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import AppWrapper from './App'
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';
import { theme } from './jss/theme';
import { CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';

const Router = (props: any) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <SnackbarProvider autoHideDuration={3000} maxSnack={3}>
            <AppWrapper {...props} />
        </SnackbarProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
)

export default Router
```

Here you can find the `App.tsx` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Home from './routes/Home'
import Header from './components/header/Header'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/', component: Home, exact: true
  }, {
    path: '/home', component: Home
  }
]

function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {
        routes.map(({ exact, component: Component, path }) =>
          <Route key={`parent${path}`} exact={exact} path={path} render={prop =>
            <React.Fragment>
              <CssBaseline />
              <Header />
              <main>
                <Component {...prop}></Component>
              </main>
              <CssBaseline />
            </React.Fragment>
          }
          />
        )
      }
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you specify on what line you get this error.

Comment: I an getting error over here `ReactDOM.render(page, app)`

Comment: The code you have pasted seems to have no errors. The problem probably lies within one of you inner components which are mounted with the `MainApp`. My suggestion would be to try removing some of the components and singling out which component is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is the issue, but your imports look a little strange:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Should be:

```
import React from 'react'
```

And

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```